# Change the Text Color in mouseover Event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I want to change the text color when at mouse over event.
But this code is not working Properly

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>

        <title>
        </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#A").mouseover(function(){
         $("#A").css("backgroud-color","green");
        }); 
         });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p id="A"> My Name is ABC</p>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in `background-color`. Also only include jQuery once.

Comment: In the future, consider leaving a comment and voting to *close* questions whose answer is a simple typographical error, rather than answering them. References: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."*, [*"Should I answer off-topic questions?"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions).

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of text, you should set the CSS `color` property.  So instead of `$("#A").css("backgroud-color","green")` you should use `$("#A").css("color","green")`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with pure CSS.

```
#A:hover {
    background-color: green
}
```